# Redis Configuration keeps on resetting

Tags: redis

I am encountering an issue in the configuration file, I have tried to use the following

Options:

1.) use CONFIG SET dir "/data"

2.) define a config file for that configuration.

However, after a couple of minutes, it reverts back to the setting "/etc/crontabs"
even though I haven't restarted the docker container.

Can anybody help me? Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which container are you using? Are you running additional applications?

Comment: Hi @ItamarHaber I am using docker for setup placed inside aws ec2 instance. yes, i do have another applications running in docker.

Comment: It's possible some other process is running the config command and modifying entries. To be sure, rename the config command to something unguessable in your redis.conf. If it solves your problem, at least you know some process is updating the configuration, and then can work to identify the rogue.

Comment: Hi @SripathiKrishnan, I tried out yesterday. and the whole day it didn't change the configuration, but when I checked earlier today it changed again. any thoughts?

Comment: Did you rename the config command? Are you saying the config changed even after you renamed the config command?

Comment: Yes I did @SripathiKrishnan. It still changed.

Answer (score 0):

just hit the same behavior with:
`docker run -d --net=host --restart always --name="redis" -v /redis-data:/data redis:3.2.11-alpine`

Comment: Apparently for our case, since the port we are using is the default and is open to the public someone tried to hack it. We closed up the ports and it didn't happen again.

Comment: eah, found out that it is some nasty worm reconfiguring open redis servers worldwide, thanks to docker it is not a problem for us, just setup firewall and rerun container